# Remove last occurrence of an element in a vector STL

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

How can I remove only the last occurrence of a value in a C++ vector?

I have this pice of code.

```
if(vect.erase(std::remove(vect.begin(), vect.end(), oldVal),vect.end()) == vect.end()){
                cont++;                     
            }                               
            vect.push_back(newVal);
```

It removes all instances of a value in the array. I need it to remove only the last specific element in the vector.

Example
Vector: 1 3 4 5 3 5 3 8 **3** 6

End I want to remove a '3' then should get:

1 3 4 5 3 5 3 8 6

Is there any canonical solution or should I try a stack os list?

Comment: You can `find` the last element of any container using reverse iterators, and then `erase` that single element.

Answer (score 5):

1. [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) will find an element
2. [`std::reverse_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator), accessed by `myVector.rbegin()` allows you to search from the back.
3. `erase()` as above.

Something like:

```
auto foundIt = std::find(vect.rbegin(), vect.rend(), oldVal);
// Find first from the back, i.e. last
if (foundIt != vect.rend()) { // if it was found
    // get back to the right iterator
    auto toRemove = --(foundIt.base());
    // and erase it
    vect.erase(toRemove);
}
```